# Particles tab is not available when I use nurbs path

Tags: particles

[image]

New to blender and particles tab keeps disappearing from the right side panel. Not sure how to get it back or why it is happening in the first place.  I tried reopening document but it's still missing but if I open a completely new file it is there.

Comment: Particles are not available from curves and you have a curve selected.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a mesh object as the emitting object selected.

Currently you have a curve selected, and curves can't have a particle system.

Select a mesh object as the emitter, or convert your curve to a mesh (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>)